# osm2pgsql fails on Mac

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to work on openstreetmaps with TileMill.

I've installed postgres, postgis and osm2pgsql using homebrew.

However when it comes to import of osm data into postgres I'm getting an error:
"ERROR:  AddGeometryColumn() - invalid SRID"

It's like osm2pgsql is creating sql which is incompatibile with postgis.

I'm following tutorial:
http://mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/osm-bright-mac-quickstart/

OS used: 
Lion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the same issue recently. 
You problem means that you haven't installed Mercator projection. You can fix it with:

wget http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/utils/export/osm2pgsql/900913.sql && psql -f 900913.sql gis

You'll soon meet a next error *"ERROR: function setsrid(box3d, integer) does not exist"*:
https://github.com/mapbox/tilemill/issues/1375

:)

Try following my notes from:
https://gist.github.com/2417488

Good luck!